# Looping over object values works as intended, but first value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, oop

Could someone explain to me why objectInfo method on the third button returns undefined for the first value? http://jsfiddle.net/PnSSX/11/

I can't figure out where this comes from, because there is no property before name...

Can you help? Am I missing something?

Best regards,
shapeshifta

Comment: Apart from the loop, you have an extremely strange object model. It's like you're using non-prototyping instances, adding a new copy of `toString` and `speak` separately to every instance, and keeping a closure over the constructor parameters. But then you use `this.` to access those parameters, and have a bizarre default-`employee` object as the prototype of `employee` itself, a prototype that will never do anything because every one of its members is shadowed by the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `loop` is *initially* `undefined` and you're calling `+=` so it gets a converted to a string, to fix it, change this:

```
var loop;
```

To this:

```
var loop = "";
```

[You can see the updated/working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PnSSX/12/).

Comment: @shapeshifta - If it helps, I had to do a double take to see what was causing it as well :)

Comment: Helps a bit, mate :) Take care!